# How to identify line endings on a large number of files

Tags: linux, windows, newline

Given a medium-size tree of files (a few hundred), is there some utility that can scan the whole tree (recursively) and display the name of each file and whether the file currently contains CRLF, LF, or mixed line terminators?

A GUI that can both display the current status and also selectively change specific files is preferred, but not essential.

Also prefer a solution for Windows, but I have access to both Bash for Windows and a Linux box that has access to the same file tree, so I can use something Linux-y if necessary.

Answer (score -1):

Related Question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/118959/how-to-find-files-that-contain-newline-in-filename

You can use linux' `find` to look recursivly for filenames containing newline characters:

```
find . -name $'*[\n\r]*'
```

From there you can proceed to do what you need to do.